# Script keeps Vector2 values after the scene gets reloaded. Setting new X,Y values in Awake() or Start() functions doesn't work after second load

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game for android/IOS and I'm using a Vector2 to move the player diagonally by pressing/tapping two buttons(left,right). My problem is that after the player collides with an object and dies, and the scene reloads. The X,Y values equals the values before the reload but i want them to be 0, 0.

I've fiddled around with these three scripts below. It might be something to do with the player object becoming inactive. (Sorry if it's messy first time posting)

//from player movement script

```
private void Awake()
{
    moveChange = new Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f);
}

void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    Vector3 movement = moveChange * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    rb.MovePosition(transform.position + movement);
}

public void ClickR()
{
     moveChange = new Vector2(0.5f, 1.0f);
}

public void ClickL()
{
     moveChange = new Vector2(-0.5f, 1.0f);
}
```

//from collision script

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    GameObject e = Instantiate(explosion) as GameObject;
    e.transform.position = transform.position;
    this.gameObject.SetActive(false); 
}
```

//from reload script

```
void Update()
{
    if (GameObject.FindWithTag("Player") == null)
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        if (timer > beforeLoading)
        {
            Scene scene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
            SceneManager.LoadScene(scene.name);
        }
    }
}
```

So the player object doesn't move on the first scene load, as intended, but instantly starts moving to left/right depending on which button has been pressed/tapped before the scene reloads. I've tried to set the X,Y values to 0f, 0f in the Awake() / Start() functions and also in OnTriggerEnter but it didn't work.

One thing I did notice is that if i tap somewhere else on the screen(android) other than the buttons before reloading level the player doesn't move and X, Y is set to 0, 0.

Comment: How is `moveChange` declared?

Comment: Also note that you should never use `GameObject.FindWithTag("Player")` inside `Update` or any repeatedly called method! It is very performance intense! Rather reference the reload script in your player and make it call a reload method

Comment: Is there any `DontDestroyOnLoad` involved? In this case `Awake` and `Start` aren't called again.

Comment: I've tried `Vector2 moveChange;` and `Vector2 moveChange = new Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f);` but currently it is the former and I put the latter in Awake().
There are no DontDestroyOnLoad in any of the scripts.

Comment: so no `DontDestroyOnLoad`, right? Also a sidenote: in `FixedUpdate` you should rather use `Time.fixedDeltaTime`

Comment: I don't have access to the code atm but the thing is that the script doesn't completely reset after scene reload. The strange part to me is that  Awake() and Start() seems to be called if i tap somewhere else on the screen other than on the left/right buttons before reload, as mentioned in the post.

Comment: Yes, there are no `DontDestroyOnLoad` and thanks for all the tips!

Comment: `moveChange` also it not `static`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had nothing to do with the code. I changed the "Event type" on the "Event Trigger" script on the buttons to "PointerDown" instead of "PointerEnter" and now it's working as intended. As simple as that.